# I have a set of recordings with me from which i have to extract only a select few clips

Tags: windows, cmd

I have about nearly 800 recording clippings from which i have to extract only a few select clips, the clips which i have to extract and store in another folder is a list that i should prepare on excel or on a notepad, whichever is easy to program with

To say my example would look like this

This is my folder
located in a path called **C:\Desktop\Recordings**

- 20140404-204604_1622719993-all
- 20140404-204638_1622737834-all
- 20140404-204925_1634300477-all
- 20140404-205903_1654712140-all
- 20140404-210135_1664564521-all
- 20140404-210924_1698260169-all
  etc. etc.

from where i have a notepad file called list.txt which will contain the data somewhat like this.

**list.txt**

1524824025

1524846905

1530242587

1555663573

1555663992

1555811052

1555820729

1555820601

I have to extract the clips in the above folder matching to the set of filenames i have in the notepad/excel above and paste/extract them on a different directory.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Place `file.txt` from notepad in `C:\Desktop\Recordings` and launch this.

It will show you the copy commands on the screen - remove `echo` and run it again to actually copy the files.

Replace `copy` with `move` if you want to move the files to the target folder, **which must already exist**.

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Desktop\Recordings" && (
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file.txt") do (
   echo copy "*%%a*" "c:\new\folder"
)
)
echo if the screen is empty then double check the path in the cd command.
pause
```